# Как применить метод any(), all()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Pandas ​предоставляет инструменты свертки структур данных для получения **сводной информации**. Для выполнения операции “логическое ИЛИ” по строкам(`​axis​=​1`) или столбцам(по умолчанию или ​`axis​=​0`) используется метод ​`any()`, аналогично “логическое И” - метод `all(`).​ Если у меня есть таблица:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
tab1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3],[10,20,30]]))
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   10  20  30
```

Дальше я проверяю элементы таблицы на условие `tab1[tab1>2]`.
Получаю:

```
    0   1   2
0   NaN NaN 3
1   10.0    20.0    30
```

tab1>2

```
     0      1       2
0   False   False   True
1   True    True    True
```

Свертка по столбцам `(tab1 ​>​​2).any()`:

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
dtype: bool
```

Свертка по строкам `(tab1 ​>​​2).any(axis = 1)`

```
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

Как получить сводную таблицу, использую метод `any()`, `all()`? Как этот метод применить практически? Пока я только получила логические переменные в DataFrame.    Вариант с маской не срабатывает:

```
#по столбцам
maska3 = (tab1>2).all(axis = 0)
tab1[maska3]
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.


0   1   2
```

А должен вывести последний столбец.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [7]: tab1.loc[:, (tab1 > 2).all()]
Out[7]:
    2
0   3
1  30
```

---

**Пояснение:**

DataFrame для примера:

```
In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3],[10,20,30]]), columns=list("abc"))

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  10  20  30
```

Оператор `DataFrame[arg]` - пытается угадать тип индексирования/фильтрования.

Если в качестве аргумента передан вектор булевых значений, длина которого совпадает с числом **строк** DataFrame, значит пользователь фильтрует строки, использую "булеву максу".

```
In [17]: df[[True, False]]
Out[17]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

В противном случае пользователь пытается выбрать **столбцы** DataFrame:

```
In [19]: df["a"]
Out[19]:
0     1
1    10
Name: a, dtype: int32

In [20]: df[["a", "c"]]
Out[20]:
    a   c
0   1   3
1  10  30
```

Для более тонкой/гибкой выборки лучше использовать [`selector's`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#):

- `DataFrame.loc[<axis_0_filter>, <axis_1_filter>]`  - [selection by label](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label)
- `DataFrame.iloc[<axis_0_filter>, <axis_1_filter>]`  - [selection by position](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ